# Chrome does not re-calculate width when height changes

Tags: css

I have a list of thumbnails with links and images, so when the user hover an `li` element, it's height becomes 100%, but the problem it works **wrong** in Chrome for some odd reason. I don't understand why in Chrome the hovered `li` width doesn't adjust to its "new" size.

*(Note: this is a simplified version of my problem)*

Also, this problem occurs only on `:hover`. but not, lets say, with `:nth-child`

[**Playground link**](http://jsbin.com/operib/81/edit)

[image: chrome vs FF]

### Update: problem continues...

See my solution in the answers, BUT the problem continues..I've zoom in with the mouse and you will see it happening..note that number of images can be huge.

### Update 2:

Force a redraw every mousehweel event fires...
`thumbs.hide().show(0);`

Comment: It's formatted like a tree. Never seen it before but it looks nice actually.

Comment: That style of formatting is an option in Visual Studio 2012 (probably other IDEs as well). I quite like it and have begun to use; it provides visual grouping of similar selectors.

Comment: it's kind of a mess. reading a bunch of CSS rules from left-to-right is just stupid. word:colon-dash;semicolor:word-blue:color;#hex ... killymself

Comment: I've been using this style of coding since 2006 actually and it is the style you should use if you aren't.

Comment: You shouldn't even be hand-writing your CSS anymore. Get SASS, LESS or Compass. Color variables alone make it worth the switch.

Comment: can you please stick to the question....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: [**Solution playground**](http://jsbin.com/operib/81/edit)

The idea is to trick Chrome to re-calculate the width, by giving the image a new height that is *almost* the same on the `li:hover` state. BUT this isn't enough for Chrome. transitions must also be applied on the `img`. This is all voodoo coding, but this is the least-ugly solution I could come up with:

```
ul{ list-style:none; display:inline-block; height:80px; white-space:pre; width:100%; }
  li{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; height:60%; -webkit-transition:.2s; transition:.2s; }
  li:hover{ height:100%; }
    li a{ height:100%; padding:0 2px; display:block; }
    li a img{ height:96%; -webkit-transition:.2s; transition:.2s; }
    li:hover a img{ min-height:96%; }
```

Comment: try to zoom with the mouse and you will see it getting messy :(

Answer (score 0):

I am new here and I am not sure if this is a good practice but I will post my observation and not a precise solution:

1. The same problem appears on Opera.
2. This seemed strange to me - when `li:hover a img{ border:1px solid black; }` or any similar css code that is not supposed to make any change to the current situation is added it all starts to behave very strange. ex - http://jsbin.com/operib/43/edit

And here it is the solution I do not find elegant, just a quick fix:
http://jsbin.com/operib/39/edit

EDIT: After testing @Carol McKay's result I realized that the transition is making the whole mess. The next link (node 58) is node 43 linked above (which is basically node 1 just added border to the image on hover) with removed transition and it works just fine  http://jsbin.com/operib/58/edit.

It seems that any css rule should be added on hover so the `<img/>` dimensions are recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

Apply transition to the image instead.

css

```
ul{ list-style:none; display:inline-block; height:80px; white-space:pre; width:100%; 
}
li{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; height:60%; }
li a{ height:100%; padding:0 2px; display:block; }
li a img{ display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; height:96%; transition:0.15s; -   webkit-transition:0.15s; }

li:hover{ height:100%; }
li:hover a img{ height:100%; opacity:1; }
```

http://jsbin.com/operib/83/edit

Comment: forget about the transitions, they are not the issue here...you can remove them, the problem still stays

Comment: yeah, it looks goood for me too. no overlap