# Chrome with height 100% images randomly doesn't keep aspect ratio and stretches images.

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, frontend

the issue is easy to explain...
I have a container div with a 90% height and a contained image with height:100% to fill its container. 
Here is the simple css:

```
.carousel-item .img {
    height: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
.carousel-item .img img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 384px;
    max-width: 497px;
}
```

The problem is that **just** Chrome randomly (but it happens the most of the time) stretches the width image like I set width property to 100% but I didn't because I want to keep its aspect ratio. 
I was wondering if it's a Chrome bug, or there is a workaround for that. 
I link two screenshots:

- http://oi61.tinypic.com/ehxlbm.jpg  <--- as is.
- http://oi62.tinypic.com/2qcl8gl.jpg <--- to be.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: image links are dead. you should upload them to here instead of uploading it to some other place. makes no sense.

Comment: might be related to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718050/chrome-does-not-re-calculate-width-when-height-changes

Comment: I can't upload images in here, I don't have enough reputation yet. In any case, images links are not dead... I see them.

Comment: yes you are right, now I see them. it didn't work before. what happens if you remove the max height and width? tried setting the img itself to `display:block` ? or `inline-block` ? it's difficult to help without messing with the code

Comment: Just tried... nothing changed. Thanks.

Comment: don't you have any development environment where we could see the code? it would be piece of cake to help you if I could play around with the code for 5 minutes

Comment: Just save the page and edit the css. :)

Comment: Chrome is bugged, even Edge works fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-item .img img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 497px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work at all... image is much bigger than its container now. Thanks.

Comment: Then try width: auto; height: 100%;

Comment: Then how about changing the max-width: 100%;

Comment: do you have a link to your page and i'll take a look

Comment: Funny it looks perfect to me?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? I can see the problem everywhere, at home, office even my client sees the problem. And it happens only in Chrome. If so, try to refresh page a couple of times.

Comment: Ok it may be because your screen resolution is very high and you can see the image rendered with the max-height and max-width values. Try to reduce your chrome window and refresh page so it gets the height:100% param.

Comment: i see... this is the fix. Just change max-height: 100%;

Comment: If this works could you click the tick next to my answer please.

Comment: I can't change max-height value... because image doesn't have to go over that height i set in the css. 100% would mean it can get neverending bigger.

Comment: no, that would constrain the proportions to the width of the image.